# install titanium module from github

Tags: facebook, module, titanium

i'm having some issues getting modules to work on my app - I keep on getting told that the requested module cannot be found.

It is entirely possible that i'm not installing the modules correctly - so, for the purposes of this question:

Once i've downloaded the zip file from git hub using the green "download" button, what do i do to import the module into my project? Not how do i tell tiapp.xml to use the module - just what do i do to install it?

Can you please run through using the facebook module found at https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `zip` file of the download you'll see there is a folder called modules. This is the same folder that is in your root of the project.

So, an iOS module should be installed in the `/modules/iphone` folder. Once added, you can add Facebook to your app like this:

```
    <module platform="iphone">facebook</module>
```

If you want to specify a version you can do so like this:

```
    <module platform="iphone" version="1.1.0>facebook</module>
```

*note: I made up the version number*

You can also add it through the tiapp editor in Appcelerator studio, although it doesn't always seem to find the module. This might be a bug in studio though, usually it works great.

Answer (score 0):

HMMMM

Two main issues here, one directly relating, the other less so.

**Issue 1**

The link i gave to get the codebase from github is wrong - well, it gets the codebase, but not in a form that can be used as a module. It is, in fact, the uncompiled version.

Versions for download [can be found here](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook/releases).

So that takes care of issue one, what about

**Issue 2**

The latest version for use is a bit broken. Seems someone (from the appcelerator team???) decided to make the latest 6.0.1 release have a minsdk of the (at this time) as-yet-unreleased version 6.0.0, and sets the apiversion to 3.

This breaks the current release of 5.5.1, so for anyone reading this prior to 6.0.0 for appcelerator, [you will want to use this release version](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook/releases/tag/android-5.2.0).